# The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0 But it appears my values count is equal to my column count

Tags: java, postgresql

Here is my Java code snippet for a psql table I am trying to insert a row into. The table contains 14 columns but I only want to insert data into 11 of them. Some of the inserted data is null (actually null from my Java code). I get the dreaded column index out of range error.

public static void saveCustomer(){

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO \"Workshop\".\"customers\" (\"LastName\",\"FirstName\",\"Company\",\"Address1\","
           + "\"Address2\",\"City\",\"State\",\"Zip\",\"CellPhone\",\"Home_WorkPhone\",\"Email\")"
           + "\"VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)\"";
try{
  Connection conn;
  conn = ConnectShopDB.connectShopDB();
  PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
  pstmt.setString(1, customerLastNameData);
  pstmt.setString(2, customerFirstNameData);
  pstmt.setString(3, customerCompanyData);
  pstmt.setString(4, customerAddress1Data);
  pstmt.setString(5, customerAddress2Data);
  pstmt.setString(6, customerCityData);
  pstmt.setString(7, customerStateData);
  pstmt.setInt(8, customerZipData);
  pstmt.setString(9, customerCellPhoneData);
  pstmt.setString(10, customerHomeWorkPhoneData);
  pstmt.setString(11, customerEmailData);

  pstmt.executeUpdate();

}        
catch (SQLException e) {
  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

}

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are using double quotes everywhere for your SQL?

Comment: What is the exact question...?

Comment: Try without double quotes around `VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)`

Comment: Thanks, I knew it must be something simple. Removing the quotes around Values ... did the trick. It gets confusing when to quote and not use quotes when working with JDBC.